# MySQL Parse href title

Tags: html, mysql, html-parsing

I have the following html ahref tags and I'm trying to parse the Title/Link text:

```
<a href=/golf-video/gary.mp4  target="_blank">Gary Full Swing</a>
<a href=/golf-video/gary2.mp4  target="_blank">Gary Pitch</a>
<a href=/golf-video/gary3.mp4  target="_blank">Gary Putting</a>
```

So, I need "Gary Full Swing", "Gary Pitch", and "Gary Putting".  This is what I have, but obviously, I'm not using LOCATE correctly.  Any help is appreciated!

```
SELECT substring(url, LOCATE ("k\"\>" , url) +3, instr(url, '>')), url
FROM evfull
```

Comment: do not escape the > use it like this: LOCATE ('k\">')+3

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUBSTRING( url, LOCATE('k">',url)+3, instr(url,'</') ) AS Titles;